# Evaluate of two elements hold the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I evaluate, on keyup, whether or not two elements have a certain type of data, as attached by the `$.data()` method of jQuery?

```
<input type="text" class="some_div"></input>
<input type="text" class="some_div"></input>
```

---

```
$('.some_div').keyup(function(){
  //do BOTH elements have some data?
    //do something
  // else
    //do something else
});
```

Comment: i don't know any browser where you can focus on a div. the keyup is probably not what your looking for. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: edited. I am using input, i just typed `div` because it is shorter, and of minor importance ;)

Comment: What type of data are you talking about? Content? Class? Tag name? All of the above?

Comment: sorry, jQuery data, as in using the $.data() method

Comment: you should probably edit your question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = $('#A');
var b = $('#B');

if (a.data('key') === b.data('key')) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something elsy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd just need something like this:

```
$('.some_div').keyup(function() {
    var $me    = $(this);
    var $other = $('.some_div').not(this);
    if($me.data('pancakes') == $other.data('pancakes'))
        // Same data
    else
        // Different data
});
```

You would, of course, replace `'pancakes'` with the data key that you're interested in.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Jx2AG/